# Dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am on creating a website, I need to process CSV files that my clients will bring from outside.
I have a question about my tables when processing CSV.
I wish I could treat the array of this mantle:

```
$Data[1];
$Data[2];
$Data[3];
```

Today the array comes out of this mangle:

```
$Data[line1];
```

But line 1 can vary and that's its the problem, I do not know how to display it dimensionally.

**import.php**

```
$result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file('assets/csv/test.csv');
$data['csvData'] =  $result;
$this->load->view('user/import',$data);
```

**result.php**

```
foreach($csvData as $field)
{
    echo $field['unknowLine'];
}
```

I do not know if I am clear, but if you have a solution for me thanks in advance

Comment: Provide the code that you're using currently.

Comment: What the exact problem? Do you need to convert 'line1' to '1' so you can still use `$Data[1]? Or something completely different?

Comment: what's you issue? where is the $csvData defined?

Comment: its CodeIgniter framwork, when you send a data like this : $data[csvData], the result is : $csvData in the view page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [array_values()](http://php.net/array_values)

> array_values — Return all the values of an array

example:

```
$array = array('line1' => 'line', 'line2' => 'line2');
$data = array_values($array);
print_r($data);
// Output
// Array ( [0] => line [1] => line2 )
echo $data[0]; // Output : line
```

Comment: Oh great ! Thats working ! Thank you, so much simple !

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop like this, this is pretty straightforward;

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) { echo $array[$key]; }
```

Hope this helps!

Regards,